# Databases. error C2352: illegal call of non-static member function

Tags: c++, sql, database

The class `CSchedulerDlg` has the member function:

```
bool CSchedulerDlg::Insert(CString SQL, CDatabase* dataBase)
{
    if (shSysDefaults == NULL)
        return false;
    dbUtil.ExecuteSQL(dataBase,SQL);    
    return true;
}
```

If I write:

```
CString query = "hello"; 
CDatabase* db = NULL;
Insert(query, db );
```

then i get the error:

```
error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'CSchedulerDlg::db '
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Set your `CDatabase` pointer to point to a `CDatabase` instance.  Passing NULL pointers around is dangerous.

Comment: You need an instance of `CSchedulerDlg` in order to use the `Insert` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an instance of `CSchedulerDlg` to call `Insert` on since it is not a static function.

```
CString query = "hello"; 
CDatabase* db = NULL;
CSchedulerDlg foo; // CSchedulerDlg Instance
foo.Insert(query, db ); // call insert on foo
```

The reason you need an instance is that every non static function has a hidden parameter of a pointer of the class type.  The parameter is the instance that the function should be called on.